# Form is not submitting after ajax callback

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I have a form which has a checkboxes field.

This field has an ajax callback attached

```
$form['checkboxes'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#title' => 'test',
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'mymodule_ajax_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'test-wrapper',
    'method' => 'replace'
  );
);

function mymodule_ajax_callback(&form, &$form_state) {
  return $form['another-field'];
}
```

When I check a checkbox, the ajax callback is executed. Then when I try to submit the form through form submit button, it reloads the same page with values in the fields, but the form is not submitted.

I have tried `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE` in the ajax callback also but it did not help.

I have added the `#name` and `#id` properties also to the submit button but no luck.

Is there any other solution which I can try?

Comment: Could you please post the code for the submit button?

Comment: The submit function is not calling

Comment: @Jdrupal When I submit the form without checking a checkbox in that field, the form gets submitted successfully and the submit function calls

Comment: Event the validation does not work after ajax callback executed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you only return the `another-field` in the ajax callback.

You probably have to make a wrapper for the submit and the `another-field`.

So you willl have:

```
$form['ajax_wrapper'] = array(
  'submit' => array(
    // Submit button...
  ),
  'another-field' => array(
    // Another field...
  ),
);
```

And then return `$form['ajax_wrapper']` in your ajax callback.
Make sure to use `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE`;

Comment: This will work by I think this is not the problem. Because it is already working for one language and for other languages it is not working.

Comment: What do you mean by language?

Comment: When you return only one field in your ajax callback, then the submit button "is not a part of the form" anymore, if you understand what I mean? You have to return all elements that you want to be in the form after you have checked the checkboxes.